# Populate DropDownList and set selected value on Edit Button click using jQuery Ajax in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[image]I have a senario, suppose that you saved some records from your submit form and you saved name, surname, country, state and city. when you call back this records, how to show on dropdown list recorded country, state and city.

Comment: Well, get your values, and create `option` elements inside a `select` with them ...? Please clarify what the actual problem is supposed to be here.